# Is it ok to check the Heroku queue depth/wait_time and set dynos accordingly after every action in my app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, heroku

I am trying to work out how to respond to increasing/decreasing traffic to my Heroku site with dynos management from within the app itself.

I know you can access `HTTP_X_HEROKU_QUEUE_DEPTH` or `HTTP_X_HEROKU_QUEUE_WAIT_TIME` and use those to set the amount of dynos. What I'm wondering is what process to use to do the checking.

Is it okay to add an `after_filter` to every action in the app to do a check against some threshold, and if a threshold has been met, change the number of dynos? I would only have 5/6 thresholds, so for vast majority of users the only impact would be the increased time it takes to do the check, and then for a handful of users it would be the check + the changing of dynos time.

Would it be too much of an inconvenience to the users? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could slow every request down to the point of turning away users. I haven't tried it though. There are ways of tackling this by using background processes.

Have a look at what others have done:

- http://blog.darkhax.com/2010/07/30/auto-scale-your-resque-workers-on-heroku
- https://www.heroscale.com/ is actually a business that's built around what you're trying to do.

Other examples:

- https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-autoscale
- https://github.com/pedro/delayed_job/tree/autoscaling

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've already got auto-scaling for my workers, I'm now trying to work out how to auto-scale my dynos. I can't quite work out how heroku-autoscale schedules its checking mechanism? The most frequent cron you can run on Heroku is 1hr. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: heroku-autoscale is rack middleware so it is running with every request.
You can mitigate the performance cost of the check by deferring it with EventMachine. This means that the heroku API calls will be run asynchronously.